# I am building a WebApp that authenticates with salesforce using a connected app

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I am building a WebApp that authenticates with salesforce using a connected app. Currently while developing my WebApp, I have created a connected app in developer edition and using those connected app credentials for authenticating with user's salesforce instance. When I deploy my webapp can I still use my developer edition's connected app's credentials if I want to use my webapp for revenue generation? if I can't use then what are the options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access multiple salesforce orgs with same connected app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958026/how-to-access-multiple-salesforce-orgs-with-same-connected-app)

Comment: And check https://stackoverflow.com/q/70051868/313628 out too (shameless plug)

Comment: @eyescream, Thanks for your answer. I am using the connected app created in my developer edition to authenticate with user's org. That is working for me already. But I like to use webapp for subscription based service so, I will eventually charge users for using my webapp. So, can I still use the connected app that I created in developer edition for this purpose?

Comment: Connected app just helps to log in and define which permissions (scopes) you require. They'll still need Salesforce user accounts. Whether in your org (Dev edition has limited size) or their org, their data, you just provide a service (mobile app?) that does something cool with their data that they'd have hard time achieving otherwise. But that's more business model question than coding.