# How to grant access to salesforce account using sign-in page

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml, salesforce-lightning

I'm working on developing an application that retrieves reports from Salesforce. I aim to create a functionality similar to what can be found on dataloader.io

On this website, they present a Salesforce login page where users are required to provide their email, password, and domain for authentication. It's important to note that the user hasn't configured any specific settings in their Salesforce account, and there are no connected apps set up from the user's end.

After entering these credentials, the website grants access for the user to proceed.

[image]

My question is, what type of authentication method is being used in this scenario,
How can I implement the same in my Node.js application?

Answer (score 1):

There still is "a" connected app in play, you just don't control it. Data loader.io people do, in their own org. Perhaps a simple developer edition.

You say "It's important to note that the user hasn't configured any specific settings in their Salesforce account" but that's not true. On 1st login the user got the consent screen, informing that the app will see email, data, able to do things on behalf of the user, maybe even log in without him using refresh token...

Go to your user's page in setup, where login history is. You'll see the app both in logins and above, in OAuth apps you authorised to access your data. This is also where you can revoke the access + admins have tools to mass block apps.

You don't need to install an app (like say managed package) to use it. Think of it like making my awesome mobile app powered by SF - it'd be very stupid to bundle android/ iOS app with oauth consumer keys and secrets for every org that wishes to use it...

Have a look whether these help: [Sitecore - How to get User ID if the user was logged in using external identity provider (Salesforce SSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69799243/313628)
[How to access multiple salesforce orgs with same connected app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68958026/313628)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, and 100% you are correct. actually my application will be used inside my organization only. not outside. it is for internal use only. thats why i am trying to figure out how to authenticate and sending api to collect the data without adding application id inside connected app for each user.  also i see we are using microsoft SSO to authenticate with SF.

Comment: Make a connected app in production anyway (you can use production key & secret to connect in other org's incl sandboxes). Think if you want 1 dedicated integration user connecting at backend (easy but bit messy when it's time to pull "my accounts" etc) or everybody logging in themselves in the browser (azure active directory doesn't matter, it'll still work). Plan at least 2 buttons in the app that will pull data from SF &prod and sandboxes. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5 is prob best for you